# Using ExpressJS: How to use app.use to serve static files vs. app.get()?

Tags: express

I'm using express to serve files and everything is working but I can't get my console.log statement to show in app.get() route statment. I'm currently using `app.use(express.static("public"));` to serve from the public folder.

Here is the full code:

```
//Server static files from the public folder.
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(PORT, function(){
console.log("Sever is running and listening on port: " +PORT);
});

//Establish routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
//res.sendFile('/student-profile');
res.send("This is the response.");
});
```

1) How can I get this work?

2) Also, is the index.html the first file that is looked for when serving static files from the public folder?

Comment: Are you importing express? E.g.: `const express = require('express');
const app = express();`?

Comment: Yes, they have been exported.

Comment: I discovered that you don't need `app.get('/')` when using `express.static('public');` However, you will need a post route method for any POST requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* directories
public
views
app.js
*/

// create server
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// import path
const path = require('path');
// use static directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
   res.send("This is the response.")
   // if you want to render a template then
   // in the {} you can send data with

   //res.render("FileName", {})
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log("Sever is running and listening on port: " +PORT);
});
```